# How to get data in MySQL table into Java JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I'm working on Java project, and I need to load a particular set of data in to `JTable`. Can someone explain to me how to do this? These are my fields in the "mrnform" table in database called "order_processing".

```
`Date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`RegNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ItemNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Unit` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Delivery_Date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Delivery_Address` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`Site_Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include you query.

Comment: Query should be any thing such as "Select * from mrnform" etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) construct [JDBC Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) for [MySql](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/CatalogSQL.htm), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CatalogDatabase-SQL-JDBC.htm)

2) load data to the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) by using [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table.htm)

3) if you'll reall question, post this question here in [sscce](http://sscce.org/) from

Comment: How can I use it in net-beans I try to follow that guide line on NetBeans but it didn't work for me.

Comment: did you add MySql JDBC driver into your ClassPath, in Netbeans only add MySql JDBC driver to the libraries folder :-)

Comment: Thanks for your resources. I have done that by following guide line on those reference. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo code

1. Design the [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) (or Vector)
2. Establish the db [connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) and retrieve result.
3. Store database result into TableModel object.
4. Construct the JTable(tableModel).

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual for the JTable:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

> visit
>   http://netshor.blog.com/2013/12/31/how-to-get-data-from-mysql-to-jtable/
>
> > '//initialize row of jTable  int row=0;  //start try-catch  try{
> >
> > //create connection with database  //execute query  //no start loop
> >
> > while(rs.next()){jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(1), row, 0);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(2), row, 1);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(3), row, 2);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(4), row, 3);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(5), row, 4);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(6), row, 5);
> >
> > jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getString(7), row, 6);
> >
> > //increament in row of jtable.  row++;  }  } catch(Exception e) {
> >
> > }'