# Display Records From MySQL Database using JTable in Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I want to connect a `JTable` to a `ResultSet` from a MySQL database so I can view the data.

I am looking for some links or code snippets describing this task. I'm using the Netbeans IDE..

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620492/how-to-get-data-in-mysql-table-into-java-jtable

Comment: This Question & Answer( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620448/most-simple-code-to-populate-jtable-from-resultset) may solve your problem

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something without showing any attempt nor effort to achieve what is asked. Questions in this format don't follow the guidelines about the topics that can be asked in SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 16):

Below is a class which will accomplish the very basics of what you want to do when reading data from a MySQL database into a `JTable` in Java.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFromMySqlDatabase extends JFrame
{
    public TableFromMySqlDatabase()
    {
        ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

        //  Connect to an MySQL Database, run query, get result set
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb";
        String userid = "root";
        String password = "sesame";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM animals";

        // Java SE 7 has try-with-resources
        // This will ensure that the sql objects are closed when the program 
        // is finished with them
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ))
        {
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next())
            {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.add( row );
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }

        // Create Vectors and copy over elements from ArrayLists to them
        // Vector is deprecated but I am using them in this example to keep 
        // things simple - the best practice would be to create a custom defined
        // class which inherits from the AbstractTableModel class
        Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
            Vector subVector = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
            {
                subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
            }
            dataVector.add(subVector);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
            columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

        //  Create table with database data    
        JTable table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableFromMySqlDatabase frame = new TableFromMySqlDatabase();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In the NetBeans IDE which you are using - you will need to add the **MySQL JDBC Driver** in Project Properties as I display here:

[image]

Otherwise the code will throw an `SQLException` stating that the driver cannot be found.

Now in my example, `yourdb` is the name of the database and `animals` is the name of the table that I am performing a query against.

**Here is what will be output:**

[image]

**Parting note:**

You stated that you were a novice and needed some help understanding some of the basic classes and concepts of Java. I will list a few here, but remember you can always browse the docs on Oracle's site.

- [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)
- [Try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: thank you for your response but I need sample codes which is short and easy to understand...

Comment: I've updated with sample code from that same website.

Comment: what is vector?? sorry I'm only a beginner.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link on a tutorial explaining the `Vector` class. The `Vector` class is considered deprecated and is mostly seen in legacy code - the `ArrayList` class is to be used instead, but the code will still work.

Comment: I've revised my answer with a response that should be very well tailored to suit your needs. Let me know if it helps you at all.

Answer (score 1):

this is the easy way to do that you just need to download the jar file `"rs2xml.jar"` add it to your project
and do that : 
1- creat a connection
2- statment and resultset
3- creat a jtable
4- give the result set to `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)`
as define in this methode you well get your jtable so easy.

```
public void afficherAll(String tableName){
        String sql="select * from "+tableName;
        try {
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            tbContTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work a lot with database in your code and you know the structure of your table, I suggest you do it as follow:

First of all you can define a class which will help you to make objects capable of keeping your table rows data. For example in my project I created a class named **Document.java** to keep data of a single document from my database and I made an array list of these objects to keep data of my table which is gain by a query.

```
package financialdocuments;

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Document {

 private int document_number; 
 private boolean document_type;
 private boolean document_status; 
 private StringBuilder document_date;
 private StringBuilder document_statement;
 private int document_code_number;
 private int document_employee_number;
 private int document_client_number;
 private String document_employee_name;
 private String document_client_name;
 private long document_amount;
 private long document_payment_amount;

 HashMap<Integer,Activity> document_activity_hashmap;


public Document(int dn,boolean dt,boolean ds,String dd,String dst,int dcon,int den,int dcln,long da,String dena,String dcna){

    document_date = new StringBuilder(dd);
    document_date.setLength(10);
    document_date.setCharAt(4, '.');
    document_date.setCharAt(7, '.');
    document_statement = new StringBuilder(dst);
    document_statement.setLength(50);
    document_number = dn; 
    document_type = dt;
    document_status = ds;
    document_code_number = dcon;
    document_employee_number = den;
    document_client_number = dcln;
    document_amount = da;
    document_employee_name = dena;
    document_client_name = dcna;

    document_payment_amount = 0;

    document_activity_hashmap = new HashMap<>();

}

public Document(int dn,boolean dt,boolean ds, long dpa){

    document_number = dn; 
    document_type = dt;
    document_status = ds;

    document_payment_amount = dpa;

    document_activity_hashmap = new HashMap<>();

}

// Print document information 
public void printDocumentInformation (){
    System.out.println("Document Number:" + document_number); 
    System.out.println("Document Date:" + document_date); 
    System.out.println("Document Type:" + document_type); 
    System.out.println("Document Status:" + document_status); 
    System.out.println("Document Statement:" + document_statement); 
    System.out.println("Document Code Number:" + document_code_number); 
    System.out.println("Document Client Number:" + document_client_number); 
    System.out.println("Document Employee Number:" + document_employee_number); 
    System.out.println("Document Amount:" + document_amount); 
    System.out.println("Document Payment Amount:" + document_payment_amount); 
    System.out.println("Document Employee Name:" + document_employee_name); 
    System.out.println("Document Client Name:" + document_client_name); 

} 
}
```

Second of all, you can define a class to handle your database needs. For example I defined a class named **DataBase.java** which handles my connections to the database and my needed queries. And I instantiated an objected of it in my main class.

```
package financialdocuments;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class DataBase {

/** 
 * 
 * Defining parameters and strings that are going to be used
 * 
 */
//Connection connect;

// Tables which their datas are extracted at the beginning 
HashMap<Integer,String> code_table;
HashMap<Integer,String> activity_table;
HashMap<Integer,String> client_table;
HashMap<Integer,String> employee_table;

// Resultset Returned by queries 
private ResultSet result;

// Strings needed to set connection
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/financial_documents?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
String dbName = "financial_documents";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "root"; 
String password = "";

public DataBase(){

    code_table = new HashMap<>();
    activity_table = new HashMap<>();
    client_table = new HashMap<>();
    employee_table = new HashMap<>();
    Initialize();

}

/**
 * Set variables and objects for this class.
 */
private void Initialize(){

    System.out.println("Loading driver..."); 
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!"); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e); 
    }

    System.out.println("Connecting database...");

try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password)) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
            //Get tables' information 
            selectCodeTableQueryArray(connect);
           // System.out.println("HshMap Print:");
           // printCodeTableQueryArray();

            selectActivityTableQueryArray(connect);
           // System.out.println("HshMap Print:");
           // printActivityTableQueryArray(); 

            selectClientTableQueryArray(connect);
           // System.out.println("HshMap Print:");
           // printClientTableQueryArray();

            selectEmployeeTableQueryArray(connect);
           // System.out.println("HshMap Print:");
           // printEmployeeTableQueryArray();

            connect.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) { 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }

} 

/**
 * Write Queries 
 * @param s
 * @return 
 */
public boolean insertQuery(String s){

    boolean ret = false;
    System.out.println("Loading driver..."); 
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!"); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e); 
    }

    System.out.println("Connecting database...");

try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password)) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
            //Set tables' information 
            try {
                Statement st = connect.createStatement();
                int val = st.executeUpdate(s);
                if(val==1){ 
                    System.out.print("Successfully inserted value");
                    ret = true;
                }
                else{ 
                    System.out.print("Unsuccessful insertion");
                    ret = false;
                }
                st.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            connect.close();
    }catch (SQLException e) { 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    } 
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Query needed to get code table's data
 * @param c
 * @return 
 */
private void selectCodeTableQueryArray(Connection c) {
    try {
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  code;");
        while (res.next()) {
                int id = res.getInt("code_number");
                String msg = res.getString("code_statement");
                code_table.put(id, msg);
            }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void printCodeTableQueryArray() {
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,String> entry : code_table.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

/**
 * Query needed to get activity table's data
 * @param c
 * @return 
 */
private void selectActivityTableQueryArray(Connection c) {
    try {
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  activity;");
        while (res.next()) {
                int id = res.getInt("activity_number");
                String msg = res.getString("activity_statement");
                activity_table.put(id, msg);
            }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void printActivityTableQueryArray() {
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,String> entry : activity_table.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

/**
 * Query needed to get client table's data
 * @param c
 * @return 
 */
private void selectClientTableQueryArray(Connection c) {
    try {
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  client;");
        while (res.next()) {
                int id = res.getInt("client_number");
                String msg = res.getString("client_full_name");
                client_table.put(id, msg);
            }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void printClientTableQueryArray() {
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,String> entry : client_table.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

/**
 * Query needed to get activity table's data
 * @param c
 * @return 
 */
private void selectEmployeeTableQueryArray(Connection c) {
    try {
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  employee;");
        while (res.next()) {
                int id = res.getInt("employee_number");
                String msg = res.getString("employee_full_name");
                employee_table.put(id, msg);
            }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void printEmployeeTableQueryArray() {
    for (HashMap.Entry<Integer ,String> entry : employee_table.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
} 
}
```

I hope this could be a little help.